# How to config gcs-connector in local environment properly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop2, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to config gcs-connector in my scala project but I always get *java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found*

Here is my project config:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
      .set("spark.executor.cores", "2")
      .set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")
      .set("temporaryGcsBucket", "some-bucket")

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .config(sparkConf)
      .master("spark://spark-master:7077")
      .getOrCreate()

    val hadoopConfig = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
    hadoopConfig.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
    hadoopConfig.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", "./path-to-key-file.json")
    hadoopConfig.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
    hadoopConfig.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
```

I tried to set gcs-connector using both:

```
.set("spark.jars.packages", "com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcs-connector:hadoop2-2.1.6")
```

```
.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", ":/home/celsomarques/Desktop/gcs-connector-hadoop2-2.1.6.jar")
```

But neither of them load the specified class to classpath.

Could you point me what I'm doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following config worked:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
      .set("spark.executor.cores", "2")
      .set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .config(sparkConf)
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()
```